# 'it' in mocha does not run on using await

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

"it" in mocha does not run on using await.

I use functions to read files asynchronously and based on the returned value, run multiple loops to process my test.
I also use the same file read functions multiple times in the loop.
I need to use await to get the resolved value from that function.
If I remove the await then the "it" runs but my function remains unresolved.

```
const subList1 = [
    {name: 'value1', info: 'value1'},
    {name: 'value2', info: 'value2'},
    {name: 'value3', info: 'value3'},
]
const subList2 = [
    {name: 'value1', info: 'value1'},
    {name: 'value2', info: 'value2'},
    {name: 'value3', info: 'value3'},
]
const subList3 = [
    {name: 'value1', info: 'value1'},
    {name: 'value2', info: 'value2'},
    {name: 'value3', info: 'value3'},
]

const mainList = [
    subList1, subList2, subList3, 
    ]

function getList() {
    return mainList;
}

describe('Test', async function () {
    const list = await getList();
    list.forEach(mainListItem => {
        describe('Main Test', function () {
            mainListItem.forEach(subListItem => {
                describe(subListItem.name, function () {
                    let valueInCaps;
                    const name = subListItem.name;
                    console.log(`name: ${JSON.stringify(name)}`);
                    before(function () {
                        valueInCaps = subListItem.info.toUpperCase();
                    })
                    it(name, function () {
                        console.log(valueInCaps);
                    })
                })
            })

        });
    });
})
```

Expected:

```
name: "value1"
name: "value2"
name: "value3"
name: "value1"
name: "value2"
name: "value3"
name: "value1"
name: "value2"
name: "value3"


  Test
    Main Test
      value1
VALUE1
        √ value1
      value2
VALUE2
        √ value2
      value3
VALUE3
        √ value3
    Main Test
      value1
VALUE1
        √ value1
      value2
VALUE2
        √ value2
      value3
VALUE3
        √ value3
    Main Test
      value1
VALUE1
        √ value1
      value2
VALUE2
        √ value2
      value3
VALUE3
        √ value3
```

Actual:

`name: "value1"
name: "value2"
name: "value3"
name: "value1"
name: "value2"
name: "value3"
name: "value1"
name: "value2"
name: "value3"`

Comment: I want to be of assistance but am having trouble understanding your problem. Your code example is incomplete; there are no asynchronous tasks that need to be awaited & you have not called mocha.run() so the "it" rightfully shouldn't have run yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the the [mocha websites](https://mochajs.org/) you'll find a good example of how to structure a test. I believe your problem is that you are not asserting anything in your tests. You're not testing any assumptions.

```
// require an assertion library
var assert = require('assert');

    describe('Test', async function () {
        const list = await getList();
        list.forEach(mainListItem => {
            describe('Main Test', function () {
                mainListItem.forEach(subListItem => {
                    describe(subListItem.name, function () {
                        let valueInCaps;
                        const name = subListItem.name;
                        console.log(`name: ${JSON.stringify(name)}`);
                        before(function () {
                            valueInCaps = subListItem.info.toUpperCase();
                        })
                        it(name, function () {
                            console.log(valueInCaps);
                            assert.equal(someCondition)
                        })
                    })
                })

            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomás A. Puricelli Roberts, but it didn't work.